# Convert varchar(7) columns to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data that is in a `varchar(7)` column that I want to convert into a `DateTime` column.

I have a select where I am split this into month, year and setting the day to 1. I am having a hard time inserting this data into the `LogDate [datetime]`. I tried to CONCAT the select but I am getting Incorrect syntax . Is there any other way to do this?

Table setup

```
CREATE TABLE LogData
(
    LogMonth [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    LogDate [datetime] NULL
);

INSERT INTO LogData ([LogMonth])
VALUES ('01/2023');

INSERT INTO LogData ([LogMonth])
VALUES ('02/2023');

INSERT INTO LogData ([LogMonth])
VALUES ('03/2023');
```

Insert

```
SELECT 
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(LogMonth), '/', '.'), 1)) AS [Month],
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(LogMonth), '/', '.'), 2)) AS [Year],
    [Day] = 1
FROM 
    LogData
```

This is what I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO LogData (LogDate)
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(LogMonth), '/', '.'), 1)) AS [Month],
               REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(LogMonth), '/', '.'), 2)) AS [Year],
               [Day] = 1)
```

Sample

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16bbc/1

Comment: Dates have a Year, month *and **day*** portion; `'03/2023'` isn't a valid as it only has 2 parts. What date is 03/2023? 01/03/2023? 31/03/2023? 15/03/2023 12:00:00? Something else?

Comment: *"I tried to CONCAT the select but I am getting Incorrect syntax"* What was your attempt with `CONCAT`, as you've omitted it from your question.

Comment: No need to mess around with `PARSENAME` as the yyyy and mm are in fixed positions in the string

Comment: @jefferson, great job making a reproducible example by the way, we don't see that often!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will actually want to construct a date from the information that you have. One way to do this is `DATEFROMPARTS`. It takes Year, Month and Day and converts it into a date.

```
SELECT 
  DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(LogMonth, 4), LEFT(LogMonth, 2), 1)
FROM LogData
```

In your sqlfiddle example, you will have to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`, as you already made some data:

```
UPDATE LogData 
   SET LogDate = DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(LogMonth, 4), LEFT(LogMonth, 2), 1);
```

Have a look: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8fa1/1)